# Based on Newton's second law of motion

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, acceleration, drag

Why different acceleration are produced in different bodies of same mass but different size?

Comment: Sorry it is difficult to interpret what you are asking here. What do you mean by 'different accelerations are produced'? What forces do you consider to be involved?

Comment: Air resistance?

Comment: @Quantumspaghettification what I try to said is on giving equal force(any) to any two body of same mass and different size, different acceleration are produced but by eqn F=ma  for equal mass same acceleration will be produced for same force..... Sry if I went wrong anywhere.

Comment: @user168633 Given an equal force on two bodies of the same mass you will get the same acceleration - independent of shape. Why do you think otherwise?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

its basically because of inertia.ie the tendency of a body to resist change .hence a greater mass means more inertia which means less accceleration.i dont know the origin of inertia but try and
look at it as a way the nature works.